# How to replace a text with image in php

Tags: php, html

I want to replace a variable which has been assigned a particular text with an image. I am including an image which will provide the details.

Look at the shopping cart option I have highlighted, I want to replace it with an image:

[image]

Comment: Are you using a 3rd party shopping cart?

Comment: I am using opencart . which i have implemented in the website

Answer (score 0):

```
//Maybe you'll only display an image is a certain condition is met? If so, then...
       if($condition == "parameter") {
           $value .= "<img src='path/to/img' alt='img' />";
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to change it in `catalog/language/mylanguage/module/cart.php` or in `catalog/template/module/cart.tpl`.

https://forum.opencart.com/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=1516